# Copying strings from a string array to a string struct which usually works for the first 2 strings but get this error when copying the 3rd string. C

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

I have this array of strings(contains 3 strings) and in this part of the program, it will copy to the struct the string the user wants. It works with the 1st two strings when the user inputs "1" or "2" but it creates this error when I input "3".

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Array of strings (names of places):

```
string Laguna[3] = {"Mamplasan Toll Exit",
                "Phase 5, San Jose Village",
                "Milagros Del Rosario (MRR) Building – East Canopy"};
```

The struct:

```
typedef struct passengerInfo {
        struct date{ // stores the date by mm/dd/yy
                int month;
                int day;
                int year;
        } date;
        int tripNo; //  Trip Number; "AE" will be added in print
        struct name{ // Passenger Name
                string firstName;
                string lastName;
                char middleInitial;
        } name;
        int idNo; // ID Number
        int priotityNumber; // priority number
        string dropOffPoint; // drop off point in strings
        int seatNumber;
} passengerInfo;
```

and the error happens at this block of code:

```
do
{
  printLagunaDropOffPoints();
  scanf("%d", &dropOffPoint);
        
  if (dropOffPoint < 1 || dropOffPoint > 3)
          printf("That is not a drop-off point, please choose again.\n");
} while (dropOffPoint < 1 || dropOffPoint > 3);

strcpy(trip[tripCodeArray][passengerSeat].dropOffPoint, Laguna[dropOffPoint-1]);
```

specifically at `strcpy(trip[tripCodeArray][passengerSeat].dropOffPoint, Laguna[dropOffPoint-1]);`

I do not know what is causing the error. I am just a beginner C student and we are only allowed to use what we were taught so I can't use memory manipulation. Can someone please explain to me what's happening?

**[EDIT]**

As I was told, I have made a reprex of the problem. The problem seems to lie on the specific string:

> "Milagros Del Rosario (MRR) Building – East Canopy"

as I have tried to change it to a different string with the same char count as I thought that maybe the string was too long but it wasn't the case.

Here is the reprex:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string[51];
typedef struct passengerInfo {
        string dropOffPoint; // drop off point in strings
} passengerInfo;

void printDropOffPoints(void);

int main ()
{
        struct passengerInfo tripStruct[20][16];
        
        int dropOffPoint;
        string DropOffPoints[3] = {"Point 1",
                "Point 2",
                "Milagros Del Rosario (MRR) Building – East Canopy"};

        do
        {
                printDropOffPoints();
                scanf("%d", &dropOffPoint);
                
                if (dropOffPoint < 1 || dropOffPoint > 3)
                        printf("That is not a drop-off point, please choose again.\n");
        } while (dropOffPoint < 1 || dropOffPoint > 3);
        
        strcpy(tripStruct[0][0].dropOffPoint, DropOffPoints[dropOffPoint-1]);

        printf("\n%s\n", tripStruct[0][0].dropOffPoint);
        return 0;
}

void
printDropOffPoints(void) {
        printf("[1] Drop-off point 1\n"
               "[2] Drop-off point 2\n"
               "[3] Drop-off point 3\n"
               "Input: ");
}
```

Comment: It's not productive to debug incomplete code snippets. Please provide a complete [mre]. As a new user please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `string dropOffPoint`. We don't know what `string` is since that is not a standard type and its definition is not shown. At a guess - it is a `char *` which means you can't use it as a the target for `strcpy` until you have allocated memory for it. Again, we don't know whether you have done that or not since the code is incomplete.

Comment: I see, I didn't know if I could upload the whole code since the bug is pretty far down so I only wrote the ones that seemed relevant to me. Yes the string there is a `typdef char string[51]`.

Comment: Please do not post the whole code. We need a complete but minimal example. Again, please read: [mre].

Comment: I have now edited it, hopefully it would help and clarify my problem.

Comment: It appears you have some non-ascii characters in the string that are wider than one byte.

Comment: I would suggest that, before you do the strcpy, you make sure that DropOffPoints[dropOffPoint-1] is not too long to fit in tripStruct[0][0].dropOffPoint. The first thing I would do is print out the length of DropOffPoints[dropOffPoint-1]. Hint: Use strlen to get the length of DropOffPoints[dropOffPoint-1].